# How to play recorder macro in SpaceVim?

Tags: macro, spacevim

I managed to record a macro pressing `<leader>-q-r-<letter>`, but I can't make it play.
The documentations says

> SpaceVim has mapped normal `q` as smart buffer close, the normal func of
>   `q` can be get by `<leader>qr`

but says nothing about playing it.
I tried `<leader>-@-r-<letter>` and `@-r-<letter>` but it didn't work.
Could it be because I'm using a German keyboard and the '@' is `<AltGr>@-q`?

Comment: Does it work without SpaceVim?

Comment: Yes, it does work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SpaceVim uses <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> instead of <kbd>q</kbd> because it remaps <kbd>q</kbd> to another function.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, <kbd>@</kbd> is not used for another function: so you play back macros in the usual way: <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>letter</kbd>

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem anymore. And I'm not 100% sure if that did the trick, but one thing I tried was changing the layout language to English and back to German.